# Browser on Android 2.2: Strange password field behaviour

Tags: android, browser, passwords

I have recently signed up to a poker website (www.pokerstrategy.com). Usually I use a tool to manage my passwords and generate passwords for me. So I generated a 22 character password using uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers and braces. This password works very well when entered using a normal PC.

However, entering the same password on android, specifically in the Android browser, the site tells me that the password is wrong. I have quadruple checked the password by typing it into a text editor on the Android phone and copypastaing it into the password field. The same message arises.

My problem now is: Where do I find information on this? I cannot ask the site as my problem is limited to my mobile device. I cannot ask Google ("Hey guys, when I enter my password on www.pokerstrategy.com, it tells me it is wrong. Check your code!"). So I'm asking you: Has anybody had a similar phenomenon? Is there a limit to the number of characters that can be inserted into a password field that is determined by the browser instead of the HTML code?

I'd really like to watch their videos in bed, so I'd appreciate any help. If I find out how to do it, I will set a bounty on this.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but a 22-character password? Really? One suggestion, have you tried using that password on a different site, and see if you're still unable to log in? I would think it possible it could be a problem on their side, with a way it's rendering the site on your phone.

Comment: Well, I want a sizeable password, usually something around 115-120 bits. However, as pokerstrategy.com does not allow for certain characters inside the passwords, the length has to make up for it. Usually, I can do with 16, selected from the full 256-character-range of CP1252, but in this case, with the reduced range, the length is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have cookies enabled in your browser settings.

My only guess...

Comment: Good idea. Checked it, cookies are enabled.